# How to exclude files and paths for Swift-DocC compilation process?

Tags: swift, xcode, docc

### Intro

I have a framework `A` and its dependency `B`. I wrote some documentation using [DocC syntax](https://www.swift.org/documentation/docc/#) for only framework `A` and would like to compile documentation for only this framework using Xcode and doing the following steps:

1. Choose a right scheme (of framework `A`)
2. **Product** → **Build Documentation** (**⌃ ⇧ ⌘ D**)

### Expected

A generated documentation for only framework `A`.

### In fact

It tries to compile a doc not only for framework `A` but for dependency `B` as well.

### Problem

Unknown reason of failure. It happens because Xcode tries to create a doc for dependency `B` as well.

### Questions

1. Is there any way to configure the process of building a doc excluding unnecessary files and paths?
2. If 1st question **yes**, so where and how?

### Details

Log info at [codeshare.io](https://codefile.io/f/1TLWXQ5xbz).

#### FYI

| Software | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Xcode | 15.0 |
| Swift | 5.9 |
| Dependency B ([Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift)) | 10.43.1 |